# Как сгенерить xml с наследованием комментариев inheritdoc?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-core

Проект .net core 3.0 и inheritdoc.io не подходит. Беру даже пример из [MSDN](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/inheritdoc) и в итоге в xml получаю следующее:

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>AutoDoc</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="T:AutoDoc.MainClass">
            <summary>
            You may have some primary information about this class.
            </summary>
        </member>
        <member name="T:AutoDoc.TestClass">
            <inheritdoc/>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Как можно, чтобы в xml-документации всё таки прошло наследование комментария?

Comment: В документации, на которую вы дали ссылку, два примера. В первом `TestClass` наследуется от `MainClass`. При этом генерируется именно такой xml, как вы показали. Во втором примере класс реализует интерфейс. При этом указан xml-комментарий с `cref`. При этом генерируется xml-файл с `cref`. И подсказка в Студии наследует комментарий. PS: проверял на .NET Core 2.1.